# An animate function and Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, animation, opacity

I know this is a long shot because it is a large script and I doubt anyone will want to read through all this *but* here it goes.

I have an animation function that animates the style properties of a list of elements. This function can be found [here](https://github.com/Wolfy87/Spark/blob/rewrite/src/animate.js). Now I know all about cross browser opacity and I can set it manually i.e. I can set the opacity of an element to .5 (50 in IE's case) and it works perfect in every browser. Just when I try to animate my opacity property through my function it does not move.

As you can see in there I have a lot of code just to get IE's method of `alpha(opacity=x)` working.

For an example of it please see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wolfy87/aqE3n/11/). Sorry about it being so messy. If you click the paragraph tag that says `Fade to .5 opacity on click.` in any browser other than IE it will fade to 0, not .5 because I am testing stuff. Now if you click the same tag in IE nothing happens.

I doubt anyone will be able to help with such a complicated and specific problem but any suggestion will be much appreciated.

Comment: looks like you're implementing your opacity logic twice, both in `css()` and `animate()`. that's bad design IMO no matter how much you're aiming for high performance. Once you fix that, animate will be dependant on a working `css()` function, and since that works, `animate()` will work. my 2c

Comment: Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)
Timestamp: Sun, 6 Feb 2011 12:19:47 UTC

Message: Object expected
Line: 1
Char: 21
Code: 0
URI: http://fiddle.jshell.net/Wolfy87/aqE3n/11/show/

Comment: Yep I have been getting that object expected too, that is down to jsFiddle I believe because the error is coming from a html tag :S and excellent point davin! I can't believe I havent done this. It will solve so much, thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: @davin If I could, I would hug you right now... I have spent hours on this and it turns out I had already written the fix in the form of the CSS function. It is working perfectly now! And uses less code :D If you post your suggestion as an answer I will accept and up vote. I can't thank you enough.

Comment: glad to help. good luck with your library!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're implementing your opacity logic twice, both in `css()` and `animate()`. That's bad design IMO no matter how much you're aiming for high performance. Once you fix that, `animate()` will be dependant on a working `css()` function, and since that works, `animate()` will work.